# PHP Check if file is png using exif_imagetype():

Tags: php, image, png

I am trying to check if a file is png before upload and am getting the error 
Warning: exif_imagetype(): Filename cannot be empty

It seems to work with one file for some reason but not with any others that I have tried.

The main is

```
$image = $_FILES['userImg']['tmp_name'];

if (checkImageValid($image))
{
    uploadImage($image);
}
```

The checkImageValid Function is

```
function checkImageValid($image)
{

    $valid = true;

    $imgType = exif_imagetype($image);  //error here

    if($imgType != IMAGETYPE_PNG)
    {
       $valid = false;
       $_SESSION["imageMessege"] = 'The image You are trying to upload is not of type png';
    }

    return $valid;        
}
```

getting it from html form here

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10000" />
        <input type="file" name="userImg" accept="image/x-png"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="uploadImage" />
        </form>
```

Comment: What do you get when you echo `$_FILES['userImg']['tmp_name'];` ?

Comment: can you `var_dump($image)` to make sure it contains anything

Comment: Try `($_FILES['userImg']['type'] == 'image/png')`. `exif_imagetype()` returns false if not an image. Are you sure you are feeding it an image/file? Try `var_dump($image)` and see what it is. Maybe it's a string or something.

Comment: yes it is definitely an image I am getting it from html form here   I will post in edit

Comment: @MariusBegby nope that gave more errors

Comment: Can I get your whole code? I am trying to reproduce the error but I don't have all the functions. I miss uploadImage().

Comment: @MariusBegby I will post everything in edit

Comment: I did `var_dump` and the string(path) is empty on certain images. I did echo 
 `$_FILES['userImg']['error']` and it says error code 2 which is that it exceedes the html form max filesize(html not php). I have my limits in .ini high so something is up with the html form. http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: You got it man, It was Just about to post a reduced version of everything. It is the MAX_FILE_SIZE in the html form that was causing the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10000" />
```

Is the error. Change the value to more, it's in bytes. 10000 bytes = ~10kb. Change to 10000000 for ~10MB.

Replace the line with this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10000000" />
```

I tested it and it works fine for me with any images.

Comment: I thought it was in kilobytes :p Ok even though stack overflow tells me to avoid saying thanks I am saying Thank you anyway, trying to fix this has taken up most of my day. Thank you :)